# Timestamp of last modification of R script

Tags: r, timestamp

A student of mine sent me an R file via email. I need to know the last timestamp of the file, to make sure s/he did not update it after the deadline. The problem is my system (Ubuntu) records as last saved the time I downloaded the file. The information returned by `file.info("file.R")` confirms this. How can I know the timestamp of the last modification of the file?

Comment: You can't, but the email headers should show when it was received on your machine.

Comment: This is impossible. R files don't store a last modified date (they are just plain text files). That date is tracked by the operating system's file system. When you send a copy of a file to someone else, the modified date is not preserved since you are using a different file system. Sometimes you just got to trust your students

Comment: I concur with @MrFlick's suggestion that you might need to trust them, but ... an alternative I've seen in other classes is to submit code/rmarkdown/docs via a github/gitlab repo, in which case you have assurance of submitted timestamps and (somewhat loosely) identities. (Even more assurance if you require "signing" of commits.)

Comment: @MrFlick But files can have metadata (although I guess that is system specific, as you say)

Comment: @user2554330 Indeed. The problem is the original file was from another test, and I need to check the new version sent does not include new work.

Comment: @luchonacho But metadata isn't usually stored in the file itself, it's stored in the file system.

Comment: @MrFlick So I guess I could ask the student to send me the timestamp in the system. Perhaps a screenshot...

Comment: If the student is the file owner, they can change the creation and modification dates in the file system.  So I think you need to follow @MrFlick's advice:  trust the student.